# Best practices for setting working directory in R

Tags: r

Relative newcomer to R and wondering about best practices (or practical advice) for the following scenario.  I have a directory structure similar to the following with some R scripts and data that needs to be pulled in:

```
~/project/
├───src/
│   ├───01_metrics.R
│   ├───02_other.R
├───data/
│   ├───some_data.db
│   ├───some_other_data.tsv
├───output_plots/
...
```

Within the R scripts, I pull in the data for example with:

```
library(tidyverse)
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "../data/some_data.db")
sometable <- tbl(conn, "sometable")
```

This presumes that when I run `Rscript ./01_metrics.R` I do it from within the `src` directory.  Sometimes I forget and inadvertently run it from the parent folder (`Rscript src/01_metrics.R`).

Is there a more robust way of coding the path to the `data` and `output_plots` directories from within the R script?  For portability, I'm not keen to code in the full path.  I could call `setwd()` at the start of each script but I'm wondering if this is the best solution.

What do others do, as this can't be a niche problem?

PS: I'm not using RStudio (I'm more comfortable in vim); I'm aware that it's possible to set the base directory for a Rproj.

Comment: you could check out the "here" package,

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the best solution.  Care to post it as an answer and I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to user12256545 who posted this as a comment.

The solution to this is the [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/here/index.html) package.  In `src/01_metrics.R` you can then define where this script is relative to the project root:

```
here::i_am("src/01_metrics.R")
library(here)
```

Then, using `here()` all paths can be relative to the project root:

```
library(tidyverse)
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), here("data", "some_data.db"))
sometable <- tbl(conn, "sometable")
```

If you have a `.Rproj` file at your project root then `here()` can use that to define the project root without having to call `here::i_am()` explicitly; further details of those heuristics are in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/here/here.pdf).